# rm command returns a message [1] 12345 What does this mean?

Tags: command-line, filenames, rm

I'm trying to remove a file and I keep getting a message similar to:

> [1] 12345

and nothing happens, I run a directory search (dir) and the file remains and I get a stopped message

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are removing a file with an `&` character in the name, and the rm command is being put in the background. (For the record, the `1` is the job number, and the `12345` is the process ID)

It is important to quote or escape any filenames that contain special characters. A good rule of thumb is: if you think something might be a special character, it can't hurt to quote. Just put `'single quotes'` around the whole filename, unless it contains a single quote mark - then it gets more complicated. You could also (instead of quotes) put a backslash `\` before every special character (including any backslashes the filename may contain) Though, if you tab-complete the shell will quote or escape anything that actually *is* a special character for you.

Comment: Eh, there's really nothing else that could reasonably cause a message in that format to be printed.